# RewriteRule with JkMount

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, tomcat7

In the mod_jk.conf I need to rewrite URL of the form www.abc.eu to www.abc.eu/cDE before processing with the JkMount.
I tried with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /cDE
```

but with no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Solution is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /cDE [PT]
```